# Move solution from production with TFS to home with no TFS. (The mappings for the solution could not be found.)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have a solution at work under TFS and sometimes for backup reasons but also to do some things during the weekends (only if there is not a MotoGP race weekend **;-)**) I get it home. Both in VS2013.

The problem is that every time I open the solution at home I get this messages that solution could not be bound to home TFS.

FYI:

- I 've unchecked all the files from Read Only.
- I 've delete all the TFS files (*.vspscc, *.vssscc, etc)
- I 've edited the solution file and remove the GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl)

The solution is working fine. The problem is that when I open it, it takes to long to load and I have these messages.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT** with pictures

[image]
When opening the solution.

[image]
Source control info, after solution is opened.

My guess is that somewhere, office TFS information is stored and each time is trying to connect.

Comment: The best work-around is probably to use git-tfs and use git when working at home....

Comment: @Wilbert I think I wasn't clear enough. At home I'm not interested to bound the solution to any source control. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What are the exact error messages?

Comment: @chief7 I'm at work now so I can't tell you exactly. Something that projects could not be bound to (my local[?]) TFS. I will update with messages when I get home.

Comment: Have you unbound using File - Source Control - Advanced - Change Source Control.  Do you ever want to merge the changes back to work?  If you created a separate local workspace (assuming you are on TFS 2012 or later) then you could work offline very easily without effecting existing work and then choose to discard or checkin.

Comment: @rerwinRR I've checked File - Source Control - Advanced - Change Source Control at home and nothing is bound to my home TFS. The merge at work is done manually. After the copy-paste operation at home, the first time opening the solution informs me that the solution cannot be bound to TFS and asks me if I want to continue "off line". There I choose YES and that's it. After that, every time I open the solution takes too long (trying to bind to TFS[?]) to load.

Comment: I've just updated the question with screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found it.

In each project file (*.csproj and *.vbproj) there were four (4) lines that looks suspicious.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
    ...        
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>        
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
```

When I removed them from each project file everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VS to unbind the project from source control by going to

File | Source Control | Advanced | Change Source Control...

[image]

Then click Unbind for each project:

[image]

Comment: No, if TFS at work is your primary source control system.  Based on your update it looks like TFS is unbinding it for you automatically when you open at home.  After the opening it the first time I would expect to open quickly from that point forward.  I don't know of a way to remove these bindings outside of VS.